# Remove last 2 digs if first 4 equal X or Y

Tags: python

I have a csv field column in string format that has between 4 and 6 digits in each element. If the first 4 digits equal [3372] or [2277] I want to drop the last 2 digits for the element so that only 3372 or 2277 remains. I don't want to alter the other elements.

I'm guessing some loops, if statements and mapping maybe?

How would I go about this? **(Please be kind. By down rating peoples posts you are discouraging people from learning. If you want to help, take time to read the post, it isn't difficult to understand.)**

Comment: Hi @Alice. Please add a descriptive example. The example which you gave is not clear enough.

Comment: Did you tried any of your guessings?

Comment: @AliTou Only sketching / mentally, but I can't see how they work without getting into creating new lists, and that sounds rather complicated. There must be a simpler way.

Comment: The way I read your question I see 3 separate question: 1) how to loop over a csv file; 2) how to recognize digit patterns; 3) how to replace the values. Please focus your question on one specific problem with a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then using loops, and if your csv file is rather big, I suggest you use pandas DataFrames :

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read your file, your csv will be read in a DataFrame format (which is a matrix)
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

# Define a function to apply to each element in your DataFrame:
def update_df(x):
    if x.startswith('3372'):
        return '3372'
    elif x.startswith('2277'):
        return '2277'
    else:
        return x

# Use applymap, which applies a function to each element of your DataFrame, and collect the result in df1 :
df1 = df.applymap(update_df)

print(df1)
```

On the contrary, if you have a small dataset you may use loops, as suggested above.

Comment: You were right, I was using pandas (perhaps should have mentioned that), just to note, I used .map() not .applymap() because I had a variety of other columns that were throwing errors. Thank you!

Comment: `map` works for Series, not for DataFrames. If you have a DataFrame (matrix) and not a Series (vector) you should use `applymap`. What errors did you have? Errors related to missing values or NaN ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your values are still strings, I would use slicing to look at the first 4 chars. If they match, we'll chop the end off the string. Otherwise, we'll return the value unaltered.

Here's a function that should do what you want:

```py
def fix_digits(val):
    if val[:4] in ('3372', '2277'):
        return val[:4]
    return val

# Here you'll need the actual code to read your CSV file
for row in csv_file:
    # Assuming your value is in the 6'th column
    row[5] = fix_digits(row[5])
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go and report back :)